# Converting List<object> to JSONArray using java

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0, ebean

im using java play2 framework 2.3.x and Ebean ORM when i try to convert  BeanList to JSONArray/JsonNode takes more time than using ArrayList created by looping on BeanList and added to that ArrayList,
lets say when time taken to convert ArrayList will be x, BeanList takes 3x.

```
public class MyBean extends Model {
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

when

```
List<MyBean> myBean =  MyBean.find.all();//will return BeanList<Device>
JSONArray myBeanJsonList = new JSONArray(myBean);
```

or

```
JsonNode myBeanList = Json.toJson(myBean);
```

takes more time than looping on BeanList and add the Object in ArrayList

```
    List<MyBean> myBean =  MyBean.find.all();//will return BeanList<Device>
    List<MyBean> myBeanList = new ArrayList<Device>();

    for(MyBean d : myBean)
    {
        MyBean myBeanTemp = new MyBean();
        myBeanTemp.setName(d.getName());
        myBeanList.add(myBeanTemp);
    }

    JSONArray myBeanJsonList = new JSONArray(myBeanList);
```

or

```
    JsonNode myBeanJsonList = Json.toJson(myBeanList);
```

is that normal behavior?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Nitek is that normal ?